# Define a function with a name in the string

Tags: javascript

I need to define a function with a name that I have in the string.

Not a big deal, right?

```
window[fnName] = function(...args) {
  // ...
}
```

But what if I cannot access the `window` object? Like inside of `Worker`, for example.

Is it possible to do it without `window` and without `eval()`?

Comment: Try using `self` instead of `window` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WorkerGlobalScope/self

Comment: There is a new standard for that. globalThis is what youre searching for. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis

Answer (score 0):

You can use `self`. It is property in both `window` and `Worker` scope that references back to their global scope. [MDN/Window/self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self)